# How to unset all but specified fields in a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm currently struggling with mongoDB and its update logic.

I have a document:

```
{
   name: "foo",
   fruits: {
       apple: { color: "green" },
       carrot: { color: "orange" },
       tomato: { color: "red" }
  }
}
```

I am trying to find a query to update the document, so it keeps only the field `carrot` in `fruits` **without** querying the collection before that.

The result should look like this:

```
{
   name: "foo",
   fruits: {
       carrot: { color: "orange" }
  }
}
```

I tried the `$unset` operator, but it does want me to specify the fields it needs to remove. I don't know them.

I tried it with aggregate, but I had no luck.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I did find one using $replaceWith

this work both with **.update** and **.updateMany**

```
db.products.updateMany(
  {},
  [
    {
      $replaceWith: {
        name: "$name",
        otherfield : "$otherfield",
        // ...
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

> _id will be kept by default so no need to specify it

The {} in the $replaceWith argument is the whole final object, so only field specified here will be kept, also as you are replacing the document you have access to the old data by using $ before the value to use

This should be working with nested field

For people using it with .updateMany, keep in mind that it will fail if you are replacing with a non existing value

If you are looking for more information [doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/#-replacewith-an-embedded-document-field)

might be late but it's for the sake of others people in need lol

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$objectToArray` to convert `fruits` into array of kv tuples. Then, `$filter` on the resulting array to keep only carrot entries. Finally, `$arrayToObject` to revert to original form. Put it in a update with aggregation pipeline to perform the update.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "fruits": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": {
            "$objectToArray": "$fruits"
          },
          "as": "fruitKV",
          "cond": {
            $eq: [
              "carrot",
              "$$fruitKV.k"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "fruits": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$fruits"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r_iLsUBu_aZ)